# How would a future British Muslim respond to rule by alien mages?

Tags: magic, aliens, near-future, religion, interspecies-relations

I hesitated to ask this question, given the acute sensitivities engendered by current events. But since the fortnightly topic challenge is religion and I would like to include a British Muslim character in my future world, I decided to go ahead.

---

The setting is London 50-70 years in the future.

For background, this question refers to the same world as in [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/15089/9207), in which a repressive regime has forced the regression of technology to mid-twentieth century levels. The takeover and regression occurred some forty years before the time in which the story is set. The top people in this regime are actually alien magic-users inhabiting human bodies but, since they are few in number and magic is fairly weak, that makes little difference to ordinary people's lives. In fact many people still refuse to believe that they are anything other than human frauds. The alien rulers are probably no worse than most human rulers throughout history.  Most people accept the situation.

Among those who don't are quite a few religious people. I think I can explore the very different ways in which various types of Christians would respond to the "compatibility issues" caused by probable existence of - and rule by - magic-users and aliens from my own background knowledge. Ditto for the somewhat simpler philosophical situation of atheists. I am much more in the dark about how Muslims would respond to this scenario.

The Muslim character I am concentrating on is a female, mid-20's, lower middle-class, unmarried member of the Resistance with a mostly South Asian ancestry. She wears a headscarf but not a veil and works outside the home. Her beliefs are not shared by all British Muslims of her time, but she is meant to arise from a significant current of opinion. In the Resistance she is part of a fractious but functioning coalition of humans of many different religious and non-religious beliefs.

Would she be willing to believe in magic or aliens at all? or would she be one of those who think it is a bunch of humans cooking up a technological fraud to keep themselves in power? What would she take from the Koran about the possibility of magic and/or aliens? They clearly are not either demons or angels, but morally mixed creatures like us. If she does accept their genuineness, does she see their rule as something that needs to be opposed on the grounds that magic is evil, or rule by non-humans is evil, or would her resistance be purely political? It is relevant to state that the regime permits religions to be practised so long as they stay in line. Decades ago risings against the aliens in Muslim countries were savagely put down, but Islam is not seriously persecuted in Britain at the time of the story.

What words would she use to describe her own beliefs as a member of the resistance? Jihad seems an obvious one, but are there other concepts from Muslim thought that she would apply to this situation? What suras, ayahs, and hadiths would she quote?

The aliens generally exhibit mild disdain for all Earthly religions and political theories, although a few express a rather condescending interest. Would she think it obligatory to make the probably futile effort to convert any she meets?

Moving away from this one character, what other types of Muslim response would there be? What religious justifications might those Muslims who choose to collaborate with the aliens put forward? Or those who resist, but not in cooperation with the officially pluralistic general resistance movement in Britain?

Comment: Is this a writing challenge?

Comment: I fear this is a bit too broad. You need a summary of muslims precepts and response to that unknown situation, for all branches of Islam. Your time-scale isn't far from us, and I gather from your world that we start from now. Then you need at least to consider the Chia-Sunni differences. And then, there are different schools of thought within both. However I asked a friend, and he explained that it is possible for her to decide on her own interpretation of everything. But you should definitively look around Chia-Sunni, Soufism, Wahabism, etc.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin, I do need to consider the difference in response from different branches of Islam. That I do not know enough about these differences is one reason I am asking the question. I had assumed my character would be Sunni given her ancestry.

Comment: @Lostinfrance - if you think that she followed from her ancestry, do have a look at which form do the Sunni religion take place there. Which school can be found, etc. Wikipedia has some lengthy articles on different schools, and I am not sure we should summarise all of them in an answer to your question.

Comment: This is still very very broad.

Comment: @James , I haven't edited it since it was put on hold. To be honest, especially given that I have never had a question put on hold before and so don't know quite how to deal with it, the demands of real life mean that I am not going to have time to think about how to edit it until tomorrow at the earliest. But I must say I don't think it's any broader than the vaguely similar question "How would society react if the existence of a god was scientifically proven?", which was the all-time top-voted religion question on this forum! My sub-questions were pretty narrowly specified compared to that.

Comment: @Lostinfrance odd it came up for re-open usually that means there was an edit (admittedly I did not check).  Many of the incredibly broad high voted questions came up pretty early in the site's existence so our gauge for a good question was real well developed.  If you want a hand with the question post it in the sandbox on meta, people will drop in and offer suggestions, or you could just post a link to this in chat and have people comment there.

Comment: @James Thank you for the suggestion of using the sandbox, which I have followed. (I'd forgotten about the existence of the sandbox.)

Comment: @Lostinfrance Not a problem, I will take a look at it.

Comment: "How would a **British** muslim.....(snip)". Politely, obviously.

Comment: I see war coming.

Comment: Sorcery is punishable by death under sharia law.  Is the person in question more british or muslim?

Comment: For the curious, there is [a rather thorough answer here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20573/islam-and-alien-mages?rq=1) by @Medi1Saif.

Comment: I think the first question you have to answer is "How would she treat djinni?" From what little I know (and I know very little), your aliens would seem to fit the definition of a djinn.