# Islam and alien mages?

Tags: magic, aliens, near-future, religion, interspecies-relations

As I haven't enough reputation points to answer or comment on the topic [How would a future British Muslim respond to rule by alien mages?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20213/how-would-a-future-british-islam-respond-to-rule-by-alien-mages) I am writing here.

---

Setting:

- London 50-70 years in the future.
- Alien invasion and technology regression to 50-70 years in the past.
- The aliens can use magic and inhabit human bodies.
- ...
- A young Muslim woman is part of a Resistance group.

---

I start with these two questions:

1. How does Islam deal with magic?
2. And how does Islam deal with aliens?

Comment: You cannot answer that question because it has been deemed unappropiate for the forum (as it is explained in the forum). This question is ever worse because a) They are two questions and b) It is not fictional at all, you should ask at islam.stackexchange.com (if it exists, which I believe it does).

Comment: @SJuan76, the original question was deemed too broad. Here this question reduces the scope of the first question, and hence making it more on-topic here.

Comment: @SJuan76 - surely that'd exclude any physics, philosophy or any other "real life" questions?

Comment: I agree with @SJuan76, this has more to do with the philosophy of thought of Islam and less to do with world building.  I recommend seeing if there is an Islam stack exchange and if so, move it there.

Comment: I agree that this is about Islam...sort of.  Without the background information and just the questions I suppose it seems like a legitimate question for Islam SE...

Answer (score 4):

I will try to give some short answers here hoping [the thread](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20213/how-would-a-future-british-islam-respond-to-rule-by-alien-mages) will be re-opened for discussion (as i might have some questions and suggestions about the character of the young Muslim woman mentioned there):

---

Islam accepts that there is something called **magic**. Scholars even make a difference between at least 3 kinds of magic, but in Islam in general (maybe their are some slightly differences about the kinds) doing magic, learning magic, etc. are forbidden. As a reference, you can read the following in [verse 102](http://quran.com/2/102) (one of the longest in the Koran) of the 2nd surah al-Baqara ("The Cow"):

> [*Instead of this,*] they began to follow that [*magic*] to which the devils falsely attributed [*the greatness of*] the kingdom of Solomon. In fact Solomon was never involved in any practice of disbelief, but the satans, who taught magic to the people were themselves guilty of disbelief. They were after that thing which was sent to Harut and Marut, the two angels at Babylon. Whenever these two angels taught the black arts to anyone, they would always give a clear warning beforehand, saying, "We are merely a trial for you; so you should not commit blasphemy." But in spite of this warning, those people used to learn from the angels the art which caused division between husband and wife. Although it was obvious that they could not do any harm to anyone by means of this magic without Allah's permission, yet they learnt that art which could not be profitable even for them but was actually harmful. Moreover, they knew it full well that anyone, who purchased that art, would have no share in the Hereafter. What a vile commodity it was for which they sold off their souls, if they had but known it!

This means magic from an Islamic point of view has some (in this verse, harmful) results but nothing (good or bad) can happen to anyone without God's (Allah's) permission. And magic is something bad which a faithful person should reject.

---

About **aliens**, I think most Muslim scholars would reject the idea of aliens. But in a small booklet entitled *The Koran and Scientific Research* I found an essay entitled "Are There Cosmic Creatures?" The author, a Moroccan university professor, stated that the Koran doesn't exclude their existence and cited some Koranic verses.

As indications of possible cosmic creatures, he quoted (I quote just the relevant parts of the verses):

> - And to Allah prostrates whoever is within the heavens and the earth,  willingly or by compulsion... ([XIII.15](http://quran.com/13/15))
> - The seven heavens and the earth and whatever is in them exalt Him. ([XVII.44](http://quran.com/17/44))
> - And your Lord is most knowing of whoever is in the heavens and the earth. ([XVII.55](http://quran.com/17/55))

These 3 verses would traditionally be interpreted that those who are in the heavens are the Angels, but the next verse shows that there seems to be something else:

> - And whatever creature that is in the heavens and that is in the earth makes obeisance to Allah [*only*], and the angels [*too*] and they do not show pride. ([XVI.49](http://quran.com/16/49), but see Shakir's translation)

Creatures are mentioned elsewhere in the Quran as:

> - Allah has created every [*living*] creature from water. And of them are those that move on their bellies, and of them are those that walk on two legs, and of them are those that walk on four. Allah creates what He wills. Indeed, Allah is over all things competent. ([XXIV.45](http://quran.com/24/45))

Again, another verse seems to mention plants:

> - [*And*] so they do not prostrate to Allah, who brings forth what is hidden [الْخَبءَ] within the heavens and the earth and knows what you conceal and what you declare ([XXVII.25](http://quran.com/27/25))

But unfortunately here all the translations only used one interpretation of the word in the Quran ("the hidden"), but الْخَبءَ also means "plants".

> - We will show them Our signs in the horizons and within themselves  until it becomes clear to them that it is the truth. ([XLI.53](http://quran.com/41/53))

About the Big Bang Theory, he quoted:

> - Have those who disbelieved not considered that the heavens and the earth were a joined entity... ([XXI.30](http://quran.com/21/30))

By the way, some Muslim scholar (from the Sunni Hanafi Madhab) thought a long time ago about humans on the Moon and asked himself how and to which direction one should pray if living there. (The direction would be the actual direction of Earth.)

Comment: I am the author of the original question that you linked to. Thanks for asking and answering this revised version. Although I am currently stalled on the story I was trying to write that prompted my question, the information you give is very interesting. Do you have a link to the booklet by the Moroccan professor, or other writing on similar topics? (It would have to be in English for me to read it.)

Comment: hm... i could try if i could find something like that his name is Idriss Kharchaf إدريس الخرشاف  i found an arabic wikipedia entry about him. http://www.quran-m.com/firas/arabicold/?page=pro_alem&id=42&select_page=allem this is a link to a website with his contacts as it seems. BTW the booklet was written in Arabic.

Comment: @Lostinfrance i could provide you the Verses he quoted in English, I'm not sure if i could find something from him or any other in English! As i don't know any scholar who writes about islam/quran and scientific research who believe in aliens!